# Подгрузка модулей интерпретатора

Tags: c++, парсер, интерпретатор

Доброго! Заинтересовался разработкой интерпретатора *name* языка программирования. Нашел довольно неплохой "курс", где в десятке уроков он [интерпретатор] пишется с нуля. Но вот незадача - уроки "построены" на языке Java. Все бы ничего, но есть один момент, который ставит разработку в тупик. Джавистам знакома такая замечательная вещь, как Reflection. Собственно, сам язык программирования поддерживает команды на "подключения" модулей. Работает это таким образом: парсер берет имя модуля, которое написанное в программе и в рантайме, используя Java Reflection, находит класс с таким именем и дальше уже с ним работает. Логика проста, но не в C++. В плюсах нет рефлекшена, что усложняет задачу. Собственно, любые мысли приветствуются. Все благ!
P.s. есть мысля сделать map [*имя модуля* -> нужный класс/метод], но вы только представьте, какой он будем потом огромный.

Comment: В плюсах также нет модулей, так что подгружать нечего.

Comment: Модули - не модули C++. Это абстрактное понятие языка программирования. Подключить модуль, значит парсер должен найти файл с таким именем и что-то с ним уже делать.